# shell how to make a copy of the first ran input

Tags: shell, sh

I have a script that takes an input and I the script gets called again but I want to save the input variable from the first run and have the condition fail for my second condition so it won't rerun the script again on the second run.

Here is my how I run my script:

```
./scripts/my_script.sh my_input
```

my_script.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

INPUT=$1

COPY_OF_FIRST_RAN_INPUT = INPUT # this won't work cause on the second run it will get replace

if [ some_condtion is true ] && [ COPY_OF_FIRST_RAN_INPUT = $1 ]; then 
    ./scripts/build-image.sh $SECOND_RAN_INPUT; else 
fi
```

I want the second condition to fail because I don't want to re-run the script again. I just want the script to run once. Is there a way to store the first input, so when second time around it will fail `$SECOND_RAN_INPUT = $COPY_OF_FIRST_RAN_INPUT` condition and won't go into the `if` second time around to re-run the script again?

Comment: `#!/bin/sh` is `sh`, not `bash`. If you want to use bash, the shebang needs to be `#!/bin/bash`, `#!/usr/bin/env bash`, etc. If you want to use `sh`, don't tag your question `bash`.

Comment: Also, note that all-caps names are used for variables that modify the behavior of the shell or POSIX-specified utilities. To prevent overwriting something that changes behavior, your application-defined variables should have lower-case names. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, keeping in mind that setting a shell variable with a name that overlaps an environment variable will overwrite the latter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to persist across invocations, use the filesystem.

This might look like:

```
#!/bin/bash
input=$1

if [[ -e "$HOME/.last-invocation" ]]; then
  # this branch runs when there has been a prior invocation
  # here, we read the last invocation's input into the variable named last_input
  IFS= read -r -d '' last_input <"$HOME/.last-invocation"
  # here, we do something with both prior and current inputs.
  do-something-with "$last_input" "$input"
fi

# this branch runs whether or not there has been a prior invocation
# here, we save our current input to file as a NUL-terminated string.
printf '%s\0' "$input" >"$HOME/.last-invocation"
```

Comment: Is there any benefit of using `read -d ''` over `last_input=$(< "$HOME/.last-invocation")`?

Comment: @BenjaminW., the `read -d ''` form will have a nonzero exit status if there isn't NUL-terminated value there, so you can detect places where the file doesn't contain well-formed content. Obviously, that needs to actually be added (`|| exit`, or (ugh) `set -e`, or the like), but at least it's possible.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy will this method only work with bash? or can this be used with sh as well.

Comment: @honeybadger_execute, this *specific* code is written only for bash. The method can be adopted to sh.